# Raw unicode literal that is valid in Python 2 and Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, python-2.x

Apparently the `ur""` syntax has been disabled in Python 3.  However, I need it!  *"Why?"*, you may ask.  Well, I need the `u` prefix because it is a unicode string and my code needs to work on Python 2.  As for the `r` prefix, maybe it's not essential, but the markup format I'm using requires a lot of backslashes and it would help avoid mistakes.

Here is an example that does what I want in Python 2 but is illegal in Python 3:

```
tamil_letter_ma = u"\u0bae"
marked_text = ur"\a%s\bthe Tamil\cletter\dMa\e" % tamil_letter_ma
```

After coming across this problem, I found http://bugs.python.org/issue15096 and noticed this quote:

> It's easy to overcome the limitation.

Would anyone care to offer an idea about how?

<sub>Related: [What exactly do "u" and "r" string flags do in Python, and what are raw string literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-in-python-and-what-are-raw-string-l)</sub>

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why don't you just use raw string literal (`r'....'`), you don't need to specify `u` because in Python 3, strings are unicode strings.

```
>>> tamil_letter_ma = "\u0bae"
>>> marked_text = r"\a%s\bthe Tamil\cletter\dMa\e" % tamil_letter_ma
>>> marked_text
'\\aம\\bthe Tamil\\cletter\\dMa\\e'
```

To make it also work in Python 2.x, add [the following Future import statement](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html) at the very beginning of your source code, so that all the string literals in the source code become unicode.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

Comment: Interesting, but this forces _all_ string literals to become unicode strings. This may not be practical, and reverting to escaping everything so that the Python 3 version works might be the best solution.

Comment: According to [PEP 414](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0414/), there is one **caveat** regarding Unicode escapes:
`when using from __future__ import unicode_literals in Python 2, the nominally "raw" Unicode string literals will process \uXXXX and \UXXXXXXXX escape sequences, just like Python 2 strings explicitly marked with the "raw Unicode" prefix`

Answer (score 3):

The preferred way is to drop `u''` prefix and use `from __future__ import unicode_literals` as [@falsetru suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33027349/4279). But in your specific case, you could abuse the fact that `"ascii-only string" % unicode` returns Unicode:

```
>>> tamil_letter_ma = u"\u0bae"
>>> marked_text = r"\a%s\bthe Tamil\cletter\dMa\e" % tamil_letter_ma
>>> marked_text
u'\\a\u0bae\\bthe Tamil\\cletter\\dMa\\e'
```

Answer (score -2):

Unicode strings are the default in Python 3.x, so using `r` alone will produce the same as `ur` in Python 2.

Comment: -1; this misses the point of the question, which is how to write a raw unicode literal that is simultaneously valid in *both* Python 2 and Python 3.